# Add a "this question is not about [X]" option when flagging a question as off-topic

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, close-reasons, off-topic

Suppose you find a question titled "**How tall is Jackie Chan?**" in Stack Overflow or any other SE site. It is off-topic. So you flag it:

[image]

This question doesn't fall under any of these. So you have to click "Other" and explain that it is... well... off-topic.

Wouldn't it be more appropiate to have an additional option saying "This question is not about programming (or whatever the SE site is about)" rather than relying on the "Other" option?

---

I considered that the question might be flagged under other reasons, like "It is very low quality", but according to the description this option is used when there are formatting problems or it is hard to read / understand.

Also considered "It is spam", but the description says that it is for when the question is advertising something, but in this case the asker legitimately wants to know Jackie Chan's height.

Answer (score 3):

You have *close-vote* options on SO as you have >3k. So perhaps you should use that, which will give you a more appropriate option.

From what I can see with my rep here on MSE, some options are shifted from the "flags" to "close".

So, if you didn't have that privilege on SO you'd have the flag option:

> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)

As I do when flagging on SO as I'm <3k rep.

I presume this is by-design so users with *vote to close* ability use it whenever possible over using flags.
It's *possibly* because it's arguably quicker given the close-vote count can be seen in the question as opposed to everything being in the review queues.